# Set up webcam microphone for raspberry pi

Tags: usb, pi-2, webcam

I am using a webcam with built in microphone for my raspbery pi and i am trying to make my raspberry to work with vocie recognition. When i run

```
lsusb
```

I get this:

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0c45:62c0 Microdia Sonix USB 2.0 Camera
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

My webcam is recognized. Now, how do i check if my mic is recognized ?

I ran `arecord -l` but i got nothing listed.

Can someone give me an advice ?

Answer (score 3):

I know this question is old, but in case someone stumbles upon this sort of issue (as I did):

This could possibly be an access rights problem. If running the command as root `sudo arecord -l` finds a card, then check if you (the respective user) are a member of the group `audio`. If you are not a member of the group `audio`, then add yourself to the group via `sudo adduser <your_username> audio`.

If none of this states true, you have to investigate deeper.

Answer (score 2):

i can use the webcam microphone in some applications, but when I try to use the jitsi-meet, then chromium doesn't understand webcam microphone. (It can use the webcam as camera without problem).

Answer (score 2):

I'm trying to use a pi as an internal intercom and wanted to start chromium in kiosk mode connecting to a jitsi conference. Unfortunately only the camera worked despite giving mic permissions.

`sudo arecord -l` showed the camera as an USB Audio device but no luck getting it to work in chromium.

I had to go into *chrome://settings/content/microphone* and select the 'USB Audio-Hardware device with all software conversations' from the dropdown menu. Default nor any of the other selections worked.

After a refresh of the jitsi page the mic started working.

I tested it on a Raspberry 3b with the latest 'Raspbian Buster Desktop' image with a Logitech hd webcam c310.

Comment: This worked for me with a Pi 4 in 2021

Answer (score 1):

try: sudo arecord -l

On my RaspberryPI 3 I get:

```
**** List of CAPTURE Hardware Devices ****
card 1: C920 [HD Pro Webcam C920], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```